# How do I programmatically create a video meeting on teams.microsoft.com?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

This might seem rather basic, it seems like it should be the simplest possible API call to make with any video call provider.

I need to:

- Get an API key for my web application.
- Create a meeting link with the video call provider using the key.
- Share that link with an external user via e-mail (or SMS, or whatever, my app does that bit).
- Redirect then internal user to the link (possibly in an `<iframe>`).
- Optionally end the meeting afterwards so the link can't be re-used.
- Optionally report on who attended and for how long.

It seems like that should be fairly simple (or at least straightforward), and for every other provider I've looked at it is, but for Teams I have struggled to get started.

For instance, in Skype this is (or used to be) simply a POST to `https://api.join.skype.com/v1/meetnow/createjoinlinkguest`.

I *think* the API key needs to be [generated in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference), and then the meeting request needs to be made [via Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings) but it also appears like it is not possible to use this API [unless a delegated user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings#permissions) - i.e. users would have to sign in via their "work or school account".

I think that would mean switching our entire user model over to Microsoft's, a prohibitively large amount of work just to generate video call links.

Is there a way to generate these links without requiring the user to sign in via Microsoft?

Is this only possible via an Azure application instance and Graph API? It seems a very long way round compared to any other provider?

Comment: Please take a look at [Create Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using Graph API. You need to provide required permissions to your app in azure to call this graph API

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT That link is in the question.

Comment: You need to register app in Azure to call this API with that permissions needs to be added to your app it is the process to integrate this API in custom app

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT yes, that's detailed in the first link I included in the question. I'm not at all sure how much that actually costs - the Azure key is used for the Graph API requests, but does that mean that app is going to run and use up our Azure quota? It also appears that the key also requires the user to be signed in to Azure and delegate video meeting permissions.

Comment: Yes it requires mentioned permissions, You will need an Azure account, yes deployed app will using the Azure services